# Looking for the Kernel Debug Kit for build 18G2022?

Tags: kernel

I'm looking for the Kernel Debug Kit (KDK) for 10.14.6 build 18G2022.

I see all the KDK's here, but 18G2022 hasn't been posted yet?
https://developer.apple.com/download/more/?q=Kernel%20Debug%20Kit

Do they take a while to come out? Or is there an alternate location I can download from?

```
$ sw_vers
ProductName:    Mac OS X
ProductVersion: 10.14.6
BuildVersion:   18G2022
```